# Unknown column error when category adding in admin panel

Tags: php, mysql

When I am trying to add a new category the error is occurring.

```
Error Number: 1054
   
Unknown column 'parent_category_id' in 'field list
  INSERT INTO `category` (`category_name`, `parent_category_id`, `category_status`, `created_date`) 
  VALUES ('DJ Remix', NULL, 'ENABLE', '2020-09-28 12:39:47')
  Filename: controllers/Admin.php
  Line Number: 95
```

```
public function category()
{
    $result             = array();
    // $result['category'] = $this->db->select('c.*, p.category_name parent_category_name')->join('category p','c.parent_category_id = p.category_id','left')->order_by('c.created_date','desc')->get('category c')->result();
    $result['page']='category';

    $result['category'] = $this->db->select('*,concat("uploads/category/icon/",category_icon) as category_icon')->get('category')->result();;
    foreach ($result['category'] as $category) {
        ($category->category_status == "ENABLE") ? $category->status_class = "btn-success" : $category->status_class = "btn-danger";
        $category->musics =  $this->db->get_where('music',array('category_id' => $category->category_id))->num_rows() ;
        
    }
    
    $this->load->view('category', $result);
}

public function addCategory()
{   
    $data = array(
            'category_name' => $this->input->post('category_name'),
            'parent_category_id' => $this->input->post('parent_category'),
            
            'category_status' => 'ENABLE',
            'created_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
   
    $this->db->insert('category',$data);
    
    $category_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    
    if($category_id){
        $this->session->set_flashdata("flash_msg", "<div id='flash_msg' class='alert alert-success background-success'>Category Added Successfully..!</div>");
    }
    else{
       $this->session->set_flashdata("flash_msg", "<div id='flash_msg' class='alert alert-danger background-danger'>Something get wrong, try again..!</div>"); 
    }
    
    $this->session->set_flashdata("flash_msg", "<div id='flash_msg' class='alert alert-success background-success'>Category Added Successfully..!</div>");
    redirect('admin/category');
}
```

Comment: Which is the problem?  _Unknown column 'parent_category_id' in 'field list_  seems like that column doesn't exist in database.

Comment: This is the 95th line "    $this->db->insert('category',$data);
". According error, error is in this line  and error is "Unknown column 'parent_category_id' in 'field list

INSERT INTO category (category_name, parent_category_id, category_status, created_date) VALUES ('DJ Remix', NULL, 'ENABLE', '2020-09-28 12:39:47')

Filename: controllers/Admin.php".

Comment: can you give your category table schema?

Comment: Where I can found the category table schema?

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based admin gui written in PHP for managing MySQL databases. Your application talks to MySQL directly and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.